# etc error in ubuntu while starting system

Tags: etc

[image: Error Screenshot]
While installing Java I did something and now getting this error.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [Formatting Help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help). Consider including the content of the file mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of your `/etc/profile` file to get specific help. Paste it as text, not a screenshot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup your existing `/etc/profile` by running `sudo cp /etc/profile /etc/profile.bak`. Then edit your `/etc/profile` by running `sudo nano /etc/profile`. Below is my `/etc/profile` for comparison to yours. You could replace your your `/etc/profile` with one from a live disk or the one below. If you had customizations in yours you can then run `diff /etc/profile /etc/profile.bak` to find the differences and add back the needed customizations then test each, one at a time.

```bash
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: It's good to mention that your `/etc/profile` has no change at all, I mean it looks like a recently installed system.